# How do you fetch and then release a direct database connection using eclipse link

Tags: orm, jpa, eclipselink

As the topic says. I have a batch import process that performs really really really badly using JPA, and I need a way to drop back to pure JDBC calls to get the job done.

Apparently you can call:

```
Connection c = ((EntityManagerImpl)(em.getDelegate())).getServerSession().getAccessor().getConnection();
```

But I do not know what to do to release and/or close it once finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager

Basically you should do it in the context of a transaction, the connection will be released when you commit/rollback the transaction.

Also refer to the performance section of the user doc for way to improve your batch performance,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_%28ELUG%29